# How can I send a string to HTML using Python?

Tags: python, html

I have HTML code that send variables to Python via button elements. I want Python to send a string back to the HTML, and the HTML display it on the page like it would if in <p> tags.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PythonGame.html</title>
        <script type="python">
            # objectGame.py
            import numpy
            def test_view(requests):
                if(request.method == 'POST' && request.POST['attack'] == 'attack'):
                    # do what you want when button clicked

                else:
                    # other things in your views if you have
                return render(requests, '1st.html', {})
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th><form action="" method="post"><button class="btn" type="submit" name="attack" value="attack">attack/pickup</button></form></th>
                <th><form action="" method="post"><button class="btn" type="submit" name="forward" value="forward">   forward   </button></form></th>
                <th><form action="" method="post"><button class="btn" type="submit" name="run" value="run">     run     </button></form></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th><form action="" method="post"><button class="btn" type="submit" name="left" value="left">     left    </button></form></th>
                <th><form action="" method="post"><button class="btn" type="submit" name="backward" value="backward">  backward   </button></form></th>
                <th><form action="" method="post"><button class="btn" type="submit" name="right" value="right">    right    </button></form></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have tried a couple of methods, and failed.

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to use Python code directly in an HTML script tag, which isn't possible as browsers don't execute Python. You should instead set up a Python backend using a framework like Flask or Django, and use AJAX to send requests from your HTML page to the Python server, which then responds with the data to be displayed.

Comment: Python can't run on the client side ([without a lot of efforts](https://pyscript.net/)). If you are writing a client-side app, use JS/TS. If you are writing a server-side app, make sure the data is sent back and forth between the browser and your server. Other than that, this question is pretty much unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to send requests from the HTML page to a Python server ([Flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28web_framework%29) is very common). Try the following after installing Flask (`pip install Flask`):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('1st.html')

@app.route('/process', methods=['POST'])
def process():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        value = request.form['attack']  # Get the value of the 'attack' button

        response_data = "Attack button clicked: {}".format(value) # Example: sending a response back to the HTML
        return jsonify({'response': response_data})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Finally, run the server.

```
python app.py
```

And go on your browser at `http://localhost:5000`.